# Heroku Not Rendering External API Data

Tags: ruby, heroku

I pushed ann app up to Heroku but the app is not rendering any data from my external API. The page itself renders, so I know the route is ok.  The data shows when I run it locally though.  I haven't been able to find documentation about this. Still fairly new at this, Any ideas.

```js
 get '/pairs/:name/recommendations/:page' do
  @name = params[:name]
                
  response=HTTParty.get("https://services.wine.com/api/beta2/service.svc/json/catalog?search=#{@name}&size=5&offset=1&apikey=#{ENV['MY_ID']}")
  @wines = JSON.parse(response.body)["Products"]["List"]
  
  erb :recommendations
 end
```

Comment: Some questions: (1) did you set the environment variable `MY_ID` on Heroku? (e.g. using `heroku config:set` or the web interface). (2) Are you using a `Gemfile`? If not, you may be missing dependencies in the Heroku app.
Use `heroku logs -a your-heroku-app-name` (optionally with `-t`) to see any error messages, that'll probably help you a lot.

Comment: Thank you. You put me on the right track.  Did not set the env variable on Heroku.  I got it working.